# MATLAB - sparse to dense matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix in a data file produced by a code(which is not `MATLAB`). The data file consists of four columns. The first two column are the real and imaginary part of a matrix entry and the third and fourth columns are the corresponding row and column index respectively.

I convert this into a dense matrix in `Matlab` using the following script.

```
tic
dataA = load('sparse_LHS.dat');
toc
% Initialise matrix
tic
Nr = 15; Nz = 15; Neq = 5;
A (Nr*Nz*Neq,Nr*Nz*Neq) = 0;
toc

tic
lA = length(dataA)
rowA = dataA(:,3); colA = dataA(:,4);
toc

tic
for i = 1:lA
    A(rowA(i), colA(i)) = complex(dataA(i,1), dataA(i,2));
end
toc
```

This scipt is, however, very slow(the `for` loop is the culprit).

> Elapsed time is 0.599023 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 0.001978 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 0.000406 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 275.462138 seconds.

Is there any fast way of doing this in `matlab`?

Here is what I tried so far:

`parfor` - This gives me

> valid indices are restricted in parfor loops

I tired to recast the `for` loop as something like this:

```
A(rowA(:),colA(:)) = complex(dataA(:,1), dataA(:,2));
```

and I get an error

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your last try doesn't work is that Matlab can't take a list of subscripts for both columns and rows, and match them to assign elements in order. Instead, it's making all the combinations of rows and columns from the list - this is how it looks:

```
dataA = magic(4)
dataA =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

dataA([1,2],[1,4]) =

    16    13
     5     8
```

So we got 4 elements (`[1,1]`,`[1,4]`,`[2,1]`,`[2,4]`) instead of 2 (`[1,1]` and `[2,4]`).

In order to use subscripts in a list, you need to converts them to [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?s_tid=doc_srchtitle#f1-85511), and one simple way to do this is using the function [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).

Using this function you can write the following code to do it all at once:

```
% Initialise matrix
Nr = 15; Nz = 15; Neq = 5;
A(Nr*Nz*Neq,Nr*Nz*Neq) = 0;
% Place all complex values from dataA(:,1:2) in to A by the subscripts in dataA(:,3:4):
A(sub2ind(size(A),dataA(:,3),dataA(:,4))) = complex(dataA(:,1), dataA(:,2));
```

[sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) is not such a quick function (but it will be much quicker than your loop), so if you have a lot of data, you might want to do the computation of the linear index by yourself:

```
rowA = dataA(:,3);
colA = dataA(:,4);
% compute the linear index:
ind = (colA-1)*size(A,1)+rowA;
 % Place all complex values from dataA(:,1:2) in to A by the the index 'ind':
A(ind) = complex(dataA(:,1), dataA(:,2));
```

---

*P.S.:*

If you are using Matlab R2015b or later:

```
A = zeros(Nr*Nz*Neq,Nr*Nz*Neq);
```

is [quicker](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance#comment-359956) than:

```
A(Nr*Nz*Neq,Nr*Nz*Neq) = 0;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `ind = (colA-1)*size(A,1)+rowA;` does? I'm not able to understand this.

Comment: I got it. https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true#f1-85511. Thank you so much . You saved me a lot of time!